# Django rest framework serializer Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `field` on serializer. Try to nest serializers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `vesting_choice_id` on serializer `VestingLocationRateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'vesting_choice_id'.

Model

```
class VestingChoice(models.Model):
id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
participant = ForeignKey('Participant', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="participants_id")
vesting = ForeignKey('Vesting', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="vestings")


class VestingLocationRate(models.Model):
id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
vesting_choice_id = ForeignKey('VestingChoice', on_delete=CASCADE, 
related_name="vesting_choice")
country_id = ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="country_id")
```

Serializers

```
class VestingChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = VestingChoice
    fields = "__all__"

class VestingLocationRateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
vesting_choice_id = VestingChoiceSerializer(many = False)
country_id = CountrySerializer(many = False)

class Meta: 
    model = VestingLocationRate
    fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 1):

- In `vesting_choice_id` `on_delete=models.CASCADE` not `on_delete=CASCADE`
- And seems like you haven't **migrate** after adding `vesting_choice_id`,
  so try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fetch multiple instances of your model, make sure that in your view function, at the serialization level, you have set `many` to `True`

Something like this

```py
models = YourModel.objects.all()
serializer = YourModelSerializer(models, many=True)
return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```